# Firestore freaking out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just opened my project under another domain (the production url) and when I opened the network requests I saw this:

https://i.imgur.com/NxgTmIf.mp4

This took forever (8 min or more.) and my CPU was hot like hell, What did I do wrong?

My app is quite simple, I suspect the root of this is this block of code:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const publish = async () => {
    const batch = firestore.batch();

    items.forEach(({ id }, index) => {
      batch.update(firestore.collection('v1').doc(id), { '#': index });
    });

    await batch.commit();
  };

  const onCompletion = querySnapshot => {
    const arr = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach(document => {
      const { vid: { id: vid }, '#': index } = document.data();

      const { id } = document;

      arr.push({ id, vid, index });
    });

    setItems(arr);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection('v1')
      .orderBy('#')
      .onSnapshot(onCompletion);

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => { publish(); }, [items]);

  const handleSortEnd = ({ oldIndex, newIndex }) => {
    if (oldIndex === newIndex) {
      return;
    }

    setItems(arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex));
  };
```

Basically what this does is load a list of videos from a playlist on a firestore's collection then after the user add a new video or move up/down save again.

Any clues?

Edit: after this madness the app does few requests and works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple trips to loading your state I think, which by principle should be updated.  Why not sort your incoming snapshot as desired before committing it to state. Give a condition to only do the sorting when 'items' has expected values.

Another way is 'setItems' as is from firestore and do sorting of data during the rendering of the state instead of hitting state before rendering.

Moreover, setting a new set of data to your state every time you sort it is mutation. React will take them as new data from before rendering which is not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow this correctly, you've got a `useEffect()` that subscribes to changes to your 'v1' firestore collection. When the the component first loads and upon subsequent changes in the collection's documents, the `onSnapshot` event is triggered calling `onCompletion`. `onCompletion` then extracts all the documents from the collection to a new array which is then assigned to your `items` state. Your other `useEffect()` statement, triggers when `items` changes, calling the `publish` function which performs a batch update of documents in the same 'v1' collection ...which would trigger the `onSnapshot` again calling `onCompletion` and the cycle would repeat non-stop.

It might make more sense to retrieve the collection's documents *once* when the component loads and initialize the `items` state with the results then write the changed documents back to the collection when `items` is updated. You shouldn't need to retrieve the documents again with a collection subscription because you've already got them in your `items` array.